# Proper SE site to ask about cloudcompare question

Tags: support, site-recommendation

my question tile is :

[**how to export more than 256 ordinary point in CSV output file**](http://www.danielgm.net/cc/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=4333&sid=36d801d348ade9f759fbd7181798f743)

> i have compared two dental model like this:
>
> [image]
>
> and the output only give me the 254 point , so i like to know how
>   could i get more point as output, also what is the means of the
>   columns ins the csv file like this:
>
> `Class     Value   Class start     Class end`
>
> [image]
>
> Thanks.

so i like to know where is the proper SE site to ask it there?

Thanks.

Comment: @gnat Does that handle 3D rendering and/or point cloud questions?

Comment: point cloud question i guess.